# using angular.js ui and bootstrap typeahead for asynchronous call to retrieve auto suggestions for search

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using angular 1.3.0 and bootstrap 3.2.0. I am trying to get data from asynchronously from my mysql database but I got some issue with bootstrap typeahead.

MY code index.html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='locality' name="locality" typeahead="name for locality in getLocality($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control size1 input-medium search-query"
    placeholder="Enter Organization name/service">
</input>
```

main.js file for typeahead

```
    $scope.getLocality = function(val) {
       console.log(val);
       var url = $rootScope.baseURL + '/api/location?locality=' + val;
       console.log(url);
       return $http.get(url, {
           params: {
               name: val,
               sensor: false
           }
       }).then(function(response) {
           var addresses = [];
           angular.forEach(response.data.resulults, function(item) {
               addresses.push(item.formatted_name);
           });
           return addresses;
       });

    };
```

When I was debugging this value will fine but i am not getting any auto suggestions please any one help me out of this problem.

Comment: did you console addresses ?? was it showing the server response ??

Comment: console.log(response);

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: it showing Object {data: Object, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: @machadevendher You have a typo in ``angular.forEach(response.data.resulults, function(item) {`` - it should be ``response.data.results``. If that does not fix it, please provide ``console.log(response.data.results)``.

Comment: ok thank u ,let me try once

Comment: it showing "undefined"

Comment: @machadevendher What about ``console.log(response.data)`` ? The ``response.data`` contains your JSON response object. You probably are doing it by the manual and there the actual response from API is JSON ``{results: [..], status: "OK"}``. So you may or may not have ``response.data.results``. What is your server response like?

Comment: @tiblu i was putting some breakpoints in .js file while debugging then i 'll get data from responce.data(it showing reslut) but responce.data.results displays undefined

Comment: @machadevendher If you don't provide the exact server response data, we cannot help you.

Comment: console.log(responce.data) showing Object {status: null, data: Array[1912]} the array[1912] is my exact data

Comment: @machadevendher Then in that forEach loop you have to use ``response.data.data`` instead of ``response.data.results``. Also it is safe to remove the ``| filter...`` part from your Angular expression in the ``typeahead`` attribute. Also change ``name for locality`` to ``name for name``.  I suggest you read the manual again - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: Thank you @tiblu and let me try once

Comment: @tiblu  Thank u very much ,some how it's working but it showing suggestion "undefined" while typing in search bar,what can i do ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77338/discussion-between-macha-devendher-and-tiblu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine Thank u @tiblu
index.html file

```
<input type="text" ng-model='locality' name="locality"
                                typeahead="name for name in getLocality($viewValue)"
                                typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
                                class="form-control size1 input-medium search-query"
                                placeholder="Enter Organization name/service">
                                </input>



    .js file    


    $scope.getLocality=function(val){
                        console.log(val);
                                    var url=$rootScope.baseURL + '/api/location?locality='+val;
                                console.log(url);
                                              return $http.get(url,{

                                                           params: {
                                                                     name: val,
                                                                     sensor: false
                                                                     }
                                                                 }).then(function(response){
                                                                    console.log(response);
                                                                    console.log(response.data); 
                                                                    var addresses=[];
                                                                           angular.forEach(response.data.data,function(item){
                                                                            addresses.push(item.name);
                                                                            //return item.formatted_name;
                                                                            console.log(response.data);
                                                                           });
                                                                          return addresses;
                                                                         /*return response.data.results.map(function(item){
                                                                           return item.formatted_address;*/
                                                                  });

                    };
```